# SQLite, VS2010 how to install

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I have a fresh Windows7 and VS2010 and I cannot fully figure out which are the needed files to install in order to use and develop apps using VS2010 and SQLite

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Morten

Comment: Which SQLite data provider do you plan to use? In part that will depend on which version of the framework you plan to code against.

Comment: VS2010 isn't a language, nor a framework. You want to do C#/.NET? VB.NET? C++/Win32? etc...

Comment: You are right. I plan to code up against dot.net 4.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use nuget extension for VS2010 for installing any libraries into your project.

> Install-Package System.Data.SQLite

It will install all necessary assemblies.

Comment: Cool extension! System.Data.SQLite is also available directly here: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Comment: Thanks - Installed Install-Package System.Data.SQLite and it works, but what i am missing is how to get SQLite into the selection of Data Sources. Any ideas please?

Comment: As i could not get the Visual Studio integration to work with System.Data.SQLite I resolved my case for the time being by using the Devart dotConnect for SQLite http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/

Comment: Check this out 
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127404/system-data-sqlite-not-being-recognized-by-visual-studio-2010-on-win-2k8-server 
2. http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/post/2011/06/04/SQLite+On+Visual+Studio+2010+Setup+Instructions.aspx